# Handling multiple page request in one page with jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and i have been trying to load multiple pagination in one page .. however after searching in many different forums and webpages I have decided to create multiple method and views and load them in one page using jquery . I am using this piece of code and it works well ..
I am able to load multiple pages in one page but could not hendle their request in the particular div tag .

For example cities are loading with pagination within my index page but when i click on `Page 2` link then it reditects to pagination generated link which is `area/get_all_cities/5` not inside area/index . I want that request to load inside the city div tag . I am new to Jquery so didn't know which function to wrote to handle multiple request in one page inside a div tag .

my index.php

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#division').load('<?=site_url('area/get_all_divisions')?>');
$('#city').load('<?=site_url('area/get_all_cities')?>');
});
</script>

<div id="division"></div>

<div id="city"></div>
```

my area controller

```
function get_all_divisions($start = 0){

$data['divisions']=$this->mdl_area->get_all_divisions(5,$start);
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url']=base_url().'area/get_all_divisions';
    $config['total_rows']= $this->mdl_area->get_division_count();
    $config['per_page']= 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
$this->load->view('area/get_division',$data);
}

function get_all_cities($start = 0){

$data['cities']=$this->mdl_area->get_all_cities(5,$start);
$this->load->library('pagination');
$config['base_url']=base_url().'area/get_all_cities';
    $config['total_rows']= $this->mdl_area->get_city_count();
    $config['per_page']= 5;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
$this->load->view('area/get_city',$data);
}
```

get_city.php

```
<div class="fwrapper">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Cities</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<?php foreach ($cities as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?=$row['name']?></td>
        </tr>
<? } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links();?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your specific problem, what you're doing is fine, but maybe add a custom handler server side to be able to combine both.

```
$(function() {
    //tiny bit more optimized to call one function when the document is ready instead of 2.
    $('#division').load('<?=site_url('area/get_all_divisions')?>');
    $('#city').load('<?=site_url('area/get_all_cities')?>');

    //assuming the paginate links have the class 'paginate'.
    $('#division').on('click', 'a.paginate', function() {
        $('#division').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
    });

    $('#city').on('click', 'a.paginate', function() {
        $('#city').load($(this).attr('href'));
    return false;
    });
});
```

What I mean is something like :

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('<?=site_url('api.php')?>?get=all_divisions,all_cities', function(data) {
        $('#division').html(data.division);
        $('#city').html(data.all_cities);
    });
});
```

And on the server side :

```
<?php
///code to handle both requests and getting the result

header('content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode(array('cities' => get_all_cities(), 'division' => get_all_divisions()));
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't understand how i am going to implement this code to my existing codeigniter methods and views . I just simply need jquery code that will handle all request inside a div tag . data is showing inside my div tag but data with link is redirecting to that page view leaving my current page ..

Comment: I misunderstood you, hold on